# Static check const char* contains spaces

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

Is there a way to check (assert) at compile time wether a const char* contains spaces or not?

Something like:

```
const char* cstr1 = "ok";
const char* cstr2 = "very bad";

check( cstr1 ); //OK
check( cstr2 ); //Fail to compile
```

The type is the same, but it may be possible to define some tricky template metaprogramming tecnique to do it.

Point is, all the info required is fixed at compile time.

This problem should be related to the "From const char variable to type" problem, which I think can be solved by compile-time hashing via metaprogramming tecniques.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you mean you want to check a string literal? Your example definitely doesn't work; `check("very bad");` is less impossible, but I still don't think there's any way to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use ordinary strings since their characters cannot be accessed by templates, but you can use MPL strings:

```
#include <boost/mpl/char.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/string.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/contains.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>

typedef boost::mpl::char_<' '> space;
typedef boost::mpl::string<'o', 'k'> cstr1;
typedef boost::mpl::string<'v', 'e', 'r', 'y', ' ', 'b', 'a', 'd'> cstr2;

boost::disable_if< boost::mpl::contains<cstr1, space> >::type check();
// boost::disable_if< boost::mpl::contains<cstr2, space> >::type check();
```

The second line fails to compile.

Comment: Those `disable_if` are the wrong tool for the job, at the very least it conveys the wrong intent - just use e.g. `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT` to get simple compile time errors.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you don't know `cstr` at compile time.

```
int i = function_call();
const char* cstr = NULL;

if(i > 0)
{
   cstr = "hello";
}
else
{
   cstr = "ciaooo";
}
```

Consider the example above. The compiler does not now what value `const char* cstr` will assume until runtime.

Basically I would say you can't make such check at compile time.

Note that though being declared as `const` this does not mean the variable `cstr` is constant. Note that the pointer type is `const`. You have to read it like this: `(const char)* cstr`. This means you cannot perform such operations `cstr[0] = 's';`

A pure constant would be declared like this:

```
const char * const CONSTANT = "test";
```

A new assignment would fail at compile time. Even if you used this approach, I don't think there is a possibility to evaluate the content of the constant at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. If that was possible, how would the compiler manage to check this at compile time?

```
const char* cstr3 = some_dynamic_function();

check( cstr3 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a script that checks the string literals that you care about, and fails if any of them have spaces.

Run this script during your build process.

Make the success of your build process dependent upon the success of the script.